# Creating a loop containing a union of two tables one of which does not change

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, union

I have a union of two tables and I count the number of rows in the union. I have to do this multiple times, where one of the two tables will stay the same, but the other will change.

To be more specific, take the mock query below as an example, the first table (above `UNION`), stays unchanged, but the conditional in the 2nd table will change for each iteration of the loop I would like to have. For example, `e.YearsOfEmployment > 1 AND e.YearsOfEmployment <= 2` for the next iteration of the loop, and `e.YearsOfEmployment > 2 AND e.YearsOfEmployment <= 3` for the one after.

I wonder if a loop for what I want to do is possible. If it is, any advice on how to construct it would be much appreciated. **Crucially, I wonder if it is possible to construct the loop in a way such that the first table doesn't have to be queried for every iteration since it will stay the same.**

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM (
        SELECT  e.EmployeeID
          FROM  HumanResources.Employee AS e
          JOIN  Sales.SalesPerson AS s
                ON  e.FullName = s.FullName

         UNION

        SELECT  e.EmployeeID
          FROM  HumanResources.Employee AS e
         WHERE  e.YearsOfEmployment > 0 AND e.YearsOfEmployment <= 1
       ) AS temp
```

**EDIT**: Here is a description of what I am trying to accomplish: I want to look for the number of unique items that fulfill (at least) one of the two criteria. The first criterion doesn't change (as in the first table), and the second criterion is whether an item scores within a **range**. The entire range of scores is 0 - 100, and I would like to find items between every 5-point increment, e.g., between 0 and 5, between 5 and 10, and between 10 and 15... so the outcome I want to achieve is something like below:

```
# of items fulfilling criterion 1 or score between 0 and 5
# of items fulfilling criterion 1 or score between 5 and 10
# of items fulfilling criterion 1 or score between 10 and 15
# of items fulfilling criterion 1 or score between 15 and 20
.
.
.
# of items fulfilling criterion 1 or score between 95 and 100
```

Comment: "Create a loop" is only *very very rarely* the correct solution to a SQL problem. Can you take a step back and explain your problem, please? There is almost certainly a set-based solution.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.  Shouldn't need to use any loops btw...

Comment: Are your criterion overlapping on purpose? someone with score 5 will be counted in two groups. If they aren't meant to overlap you can use a `GROUP BY` to get what you want. No loops. Just let SQL Server worry about caching your fixed table.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid they are not supposed to overlap, sorry that I didn't make it clear!

Answer (score 1):

This query assigns the years into five year buckets - run it and see

```
    SELECT  e.EmployeeID, (e.YearsOfEmployment -1) / 5 as yeargroup
      FROM  HumanResources.Employee AS e
```

This query counts how many are in each bucket:

```
    SELECT  (e.YearsOfEmployment -1) / 5 as yeargroup, COUNT(*) 
      FROM  HumanResources.Employee AS e
    GROUP BY (e.YearsOfEmployment -1) / 5
```

and this query sticks it all together:

```
SELECT yeargroup, COUNT(*)  EmployeeCount
FROM (
    -- first get the unique list of employees - they might be in both tables
    -- so we need UNION not UNION ALL
    SELECT  e.employeeid, 
    (e.YearsOfEmployment -1) / 5 as yeargroup
      FROM  HumanResources.Employee AS e
      JOIN  Sales.SalesPerson AS s
            ON  e.FullName = s.FullName

     UNION

     SELECT  e.employeeid, 
    (e.YearsOfEmployment -1) / 5 as yeargroup
      FROM  HumanResources.Employee AS e
   ) AS temp
GROUP BY yeargroup
```

Comment: Re: Q1 - Yes, the same employees can definitely be in both tables. Re: Q2 - EmployeeIDs are unique in both tables -- that is, there are not duplicated ID in Table 1 and there are not duplicated IDs in Table 2 either.

Comment: OK then.... try the query and see if it gives you roughly the answer you want. Also hot tip: Don't use `UNION` when you should be using `UNION ALL`

Comment: Just a question about `UNION ALL` vs. `UNION`, Table 1 and Table 2 have overlapping employeeIDs, but I only want to count the unique IDs -- that is, if an employeeID `123456` occurs in both tables, I only want to count it once, should I instead use `UNION`?

Comment: Well spotted - yes UNION applies a distinct (with associated performance penalty) whereas UNION ALL does not apply a distinct. So UNION ALL in my answer will incorrectly count a person twice in both tables. So the query has to be written another way - I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

A classic way to "create" a loop is SQL is to use a [table of numbers](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1). 
It is simply a table with numbers from 1 to some large enough value.
If you need to loop, say, 20 times, select 20 rows from a table of numbers.

In the query below I generate a table of 1000 numbers on the fly and pick 20 rows from it (`CTE_Numbers`). In production I use a permanent table with 100K rows.

For each row in `CTE_Numbers` I run your query using `CROSS APPLY`, which allows to pass the current row's number into the logic of the query.

```
WITH
e1 AS
(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS T(N)
) -- 10
,e2 AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS N FROM e1 AS a CROSS JOIN e1 AS b
) -- 10*10
,e3 AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS N FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e2
) -- 10*100
,CTE_Numbers
AS
(
    SELECT TOP(20)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Number
    FROM e3
    ORDER BY Number
)
SELECT
    CTE_Numbers.Number
    ,CA.cc
FROM
    CTE_Numbers
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS cc
        FROM
            (
                SELECT e.EmployeeID
                FROM
                    HumanResources.Employee AS e
                    INNER JOIN Sales.SalesPerson AS s ON e.FullName = s.FullName

                UNION

                SELECT e.EmployeeID
                FROM
                    HumanResources.Employee AS e
                WHERE
                    e.YearsOfEmployment > CTE_Numbers.Number - 1
                    AND e.YearsOfEmployment <= CTE_Numbers.Number
            ) AS Temp
    ) AS CA
ORDER BY Number;
```